# Windows 7 on an EEE PC 901 - Is it a practical change?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-xp

I am currently running WinXP on my EEE PC 901, and I'm happy to say that it runs really well. But this did not come with out significant manipulation of the OS. Here's the basic steps I took:

1. Install XP
2. Modify registry to install
3. Install bare essential drivers
4. Relocate page file to d:\ (remember, this model has two SSD's, one roughly 3.6gb, and the other roughly 16gb - XP won't run on the bigger drive, only the smaller one)
5. Install remaining drivers
6. skip normal updates, install service pack 2 straight away.
7. modify system registry to place service pack  backup folder into new Program Files directory on D drive (where software is being installed).
8. Change My Documents folder to sit on D drive.
9. Install .net framework
10. Install remaining updates and service pack 3 (the hidden backup folders in the c:\Windows directory are deleted after every update as well as the contents of the service pack downloads folder in order to continually free up space). I have also found that Disktrix UltimateDefrag to be brilliant at keeping the system clean and tidy.

This is roughly the order I did things in. In this configuration the machine works really well.

QUESTION: Can this kind of configuration be implemented with Windows 7 to achieve the same result on this machine?

Thanks in advance.
Dave.

Comment: If you have 2 SSDs, one 3.6 GB and the other 16GB, you can't even install windows 7, because of lack of free space.

Comment: that's what I thought. Strictly speaking you can't install XP either if you are going beyond Service pack 2 - but I did it, by utilising both drives using the registry, and it works well. I was just hoping that a similar procedure would work.

Comment: You could probably make your own windows 7 installation which wouldn't consume as much free space, but I don't know how to do it. Maybe programs such as nLite will help?

Comment: How much memory is on the netbook?  using anything but Starter Edition might cause the machine to run horribly slowly due to constant paging